# Concatenating strings to get object name

Tags: r

```
a <- "name"
df$a
```

Here, df is my data frame, and name is one of the column names of data frame df. How could I command R to execute code by considering (a) to be an object name instead of a character?

Comment: `df[[a]]`, I suggest you read [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Extract.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following. First remove a column in which you want to work. After that, turn it into your desired object.

```
Example:
A = factor (a)
A = vector (a)
```

1 - You can only concatenate vectors.

2- A letter "a" is not sensitive using the name of an object. Use another name, for example: Work1